# Postgresql change column type from UUID to int4

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to change dataType of column from `UUID` to `int4`

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ALTER COLUMN columnA TYPE int4(32);
```

But it is giving me an error.

```
ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "int4"
```

I tried to search on internet and found that I have to use `USING` but don't know how to use it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really turn a UID into an int.  There are just too many values, so you run the risk of collisions (which rises to 100% as the table gets bigger).

My guess is that you really want an `id` column on the table.  If so, add a new column and remove the old one:

```
alter table tableA add a_id int generated always as identity,
                   drop columnA;
```

Note:  in older versions of Postgres, you would use `serial` instead of `int generated always as identity`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `32` is syntactically treated as a modifier. Modifiers are allowed for numeric and decimal types, but not for plain ints, [int4(xxx)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT) is not a valid type in Postgres (I believe it is in mysql) `int4` is just an alias for `integer`.

Comment: That is a different question. Maybe there is no (default) type coercion from UUID to integer. (IIRC UUIDs need 128 bits of storage, which is not even representable  in a bigint)